# convert json to java object by Gson cast exception

Tags: android, gson

I have this json forms:

```
[
{
    "command":"",
    "name":"گزارش صدور",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "command":"ReportDaily",
            "name":"Daily",
            "children":[],
            "path":"/Sa/Certificates_Daily",
            "params":
            {
                "PeriodType":"1",
                "District":"0"
            }
        },
        {
            "command":"ReportWeekly",
            "name":"Weekly",
            "children":[],
            "path":"/Sa/Certificates_Daily",
            "params":
            {
                "PeriodType":"2",
                "District":"0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "path":"",
    "params":{}
},...
```

now I want to convert it to java object, for that I have created this pojo class:

```
public class HierarchicalResource {
public String command;
public String name;
public List<HierarchicalResource> children;
public String path;
public Params params;


public class Params {
    public String PeriodType;
    public String District;
}
}
```

by **Gson()** I turn this json to java object like this:

```
 return new Gson().fromJson(sb.toString(),new TypeToken<HierarchicalResource[]>(){}.getType());
```

but I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.views.HierarchicalResource[] cannot be cast to com.views.HierarchicalResource
```

why It can not cast my class to HierarchicalResource?

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert your json in to POJO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your method is declared to return `com.views.HierarchicalResource`, but you returning an array `com.views.HierarchicalResource[]`.

change method return type to `com.views.HierarchicalResource[]`